# check for ascii plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I check if the uploaded file is ascii plain text?

```
$("#my_file").change(function(){
    //alert if not ascii 
});
<input type="file" name="my_file" id="my_file" />
```

Comment: When you want to check this? Before uploading or after?

Comment: <form> tag has an attribute called accept-charset. You can set that to ASCII. But I'm not sure if browser will do the work for you or not.

Answer (score 5):

Using the [HTML5 file APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) (which are not yet finalized and not supported by all versions of all major browsers) you could read the raw file contents via `FileReader.readAsBinaryString(file)` and ensure that each byte (character) has a value in [the ASCII character range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (0-127).

For example ([see working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KQYNe/5/)):

```javascript
function ensureAsciiFile(evt) {
  var file, files=evt.target.files;
  for (var i=0; file=files[i]; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(theFile, theReader) {
      return function(e) {
        var fileContents = theReader.result;
        if (fileContents.match(/[^\u0000-\u007f]/)) {
          alert('ERROR: non-ASCII file "' + theFile.name + '"');
        } else {
          alert('OK: ASCII file "' + theFile.name + '"');
        }
      };
    })(file, reader);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  }
}
$('#my_file').change(ensureAsciiFile);
```

Comment: You can probably use a regular expression to test the flie rather than looping over every character.

Comment: To test the ASCII character set: `var re = new RegExp('[^\\u0000-\\u007f]');` so that the RegExp `re.test(string)` will return true if there is a character outside the range 0-128 (decimal);

Comment: @RobG: ack, flubbed the upper boundary (it's too late to be converting decimal to hex in my head...)